# Git push error: Unable to create '/tmp/project/refs/heads/master.lock': Permission denied

Tags: git

I am trying to push a repository from a Git server to local git repository and getting below error:

```
$ git push origin master
Password:
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 211 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': Unable to create '/tmp/project/refs/heads/master.lock': Permission denied
To ssh://tmpuser@cltprfusapp04:/tmp/project
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://tmpuser@cltprfusapp04:/tmp/project'
```

Comment: Why don't you pull from the local repository instead?

Answer (score 1):

It look like your user doesn't have the right to push to `cltprfusapp04` as `tmpuser`.

Ask your admin to `chown -R tmpuser /tmp/project` or do it yourself if you have sudo right.